# Can't inject repository on some controller Typo3

Tags: dependency-injection, controller, typo3, repository, typo3-7.6.x

In my custom controller, i'm trying to inject a repository as a dependecy, like this

```
class FundedProjectController extends ActionController {


    /**
     * @var \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository
     */
    protected $newsRepository;


    /**
     * Inject a news repository to enable DI
     *
     * @param \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository $newsRepository
     */
    public function injectNewsRepository(\GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository $newsRepository)
    {
        $this->newsRepository = $newsRepository;
    }
...
```

But when I call it in my **previewAction**, i have an error saying that my $this->newsRepository is null.

But this injection is working on this controller, but I can't figure out why...

> class NewsController extends NewsBaseController

I'm working on 7.6.32, stagging website but production mode enable, all caches cleared (also tried with **?no_cache=1**, also tried with "@inject"

Comment: It's an unlikely reason, but have you dumped the autoloader cache? In 7.6 that is mandatory to get injection to work.

Comment: No I haven', I've only clear the cache

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 now requires to *configure* dependency injection. It does not work automatically any more. Basically you need to add a special `Configuration/Services.yaml` file. See [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#configure-dependency-injection-in-extensions) how to configure it.

Comment: "I'm working on 7.6.32" Services.yaml shouldn't apply to him.

Comment: @Waldgeist Clear all caches in the Install tool (!!!) and try again :)

Comment: "please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer